# What does "as specified" mean?

Tags: meaning

> It may be unlawful for any driver to operate a vehicle without wearing
>   the proper seat belt while it is being operated on a public highway or
>   road **as specified** in the applicable vehicle Code.

Does "as specified ..." mean "according to the applicable vehicle code"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vehicle Code will *specify* many things. Something that it specifies *specified* in the code. ***As specified*** means *in the manner specified*, or *to the degree specified*, or really whatever context-specific phrase makes sense in place of the *as*. It could also be replaced with *in accordance to the specifications of the applicable...*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *"according to the applicable vehicle code"* is quite accurate, or, at best, it is somewhat ambiguous.

I think that, in your example sentence, *"as specified in the vehicle code"* could almost mean two slightly different things.:

- **A.** It is written (specified) in *"the applicable Vehicle Code"* that *"It
  may be unlawful  for any driver to operate a vehicle without wearing
  the proper seat belt while it is being operated on a public highway
  or road."* (Maybe not that exact sentence but something with the same meaning.)
- **B.** Whether or not *"It"* **is** *"unlawful  for any driver to operate a vehicle without wearing the proper seat belt while it is being operated on a public highway or road"* is specified in whichever *"vehicle code"* is *"applicable"* to you. (In the U.S.A., different states have different vehicle codes and they don't all have the same seatbelt laws.)

Your guess of the meaning seems to me to be **A**, but, based on evidence will presently explain, I think **B** is more likely to be the meaning of this sentence.

1. The sentence says that *"it **may be** unlawful"*, but then it uses the phrase *"**any** driver."* The only reasons I can think of to use the verb form *"may be"* rather than *is*, are if: **a.)** The truth of the sentence depends on who the reader/listener is, where, what, or when they are driving, etc.; or **b.)** The writer/speaker simply doesn't know the law for certain, which is unlikely given the formal style and legal subject matter.
2. The sentence says *"the **applicable** vehicle code."* If only only one "vehicle code" were "applicable" to all readers/listeners, then there wouldn't be any need to include the word *"applicable."* It is still possible that every "vehicle code" which might be "applicable" **specifies** the same law, but this sentence seems like an oddly indirect way to convey such a meaning.

**Now for some discussion that might help you understand this phrase and others like it.**

***Specify*** is related to *specific* (and also *special*.) The meanings *"to state explicitly or in detail"* and (possibly) *"to include in a specification"* (both from The American Heritage Dictionary, 4th ed.) both might apply here.

Among the several definitions of the word ***as*** given by the Fourth Edition of The American Heritage Dictionary, the following is the only one possibly appropriate here:

> **3.** When taken into consideration in a specific relation or form: *this definition **as** distinguished from the second one.*

The dictionary also asserts that this meaning of the word is an "adverb." Unfortunately, traditional English grammar uses the word "adverb" to refer to a number of words that behave quite differently from each other. Personally, this use of the word seems similar to a complimentizer(such as *that* or *which*), (and reminds me of subordinating conjunctions.)

Note that, in both your example and the dictionary's, *"as"* is the head word of a phrase which is actually just a reduced sentence (Words in brackets, [ ], may be added without changing the meaning or grammaticality though they may cause confusion with other meanings of *as*.):

Main-Sentence + *"as* [it is] *specified in the applicable vehicle code."*
= Main-Sentence + *as the applicable vehicle code specifies.*
= *The applicable vehicle code specifies that* + Main-Sentence + *, and that is true.*

*"this definition"* + *"as* [it is] *distinguished from the second one."* REMINDS YOU  **to distinguish*** "this definition"* *"from the second one."*

Note that the dictionary's example seems to be affecting either a noun (*"definition"*) or a noun phrase (*"this definition"*), whereas yours seems to be affecting either the whole sentence or the verb *"may be"*. This, along with the somewhat unclear connection between the two meanings, might be cause (a good reason) to argue that it is actually a slightly different use of the word.

**Whatever the grammar behind this is, here are some example constructions.**

Verb(+Objects)+***as specified.*** by itself implies either that something was specified previously in the text, or that you should already know what or who is specifying whatever is "as specified."

Verb(+Objects)+***as specified by*** [eg. the applicable vehicle code, the highway commission, Bob] tells that whatever follows *by* did the specifying.

Verb(+Objects)+***as specified in*** [eg. the applicable vehicle code, Vienna, the The Tunisian Constitution, the previous session, the living room] tells you either where or when something was specified or where you may find the specifications written.

Verb(+Objects)+***as specified for*** [eg. Texas drivers, the particular engine, most safety applications, LTE systems] tells you who or what a specification applies to or is for the benefit of; or in what situations it applies.

and so on with *on*, *with*, *at* and probably any other preposition you can think of, though most are unlikely to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It means we have already written this somewhere else, go and look there for more detail.

So in this sentence (which is usual government gobbledygook) it means that in a separate vehicle code for your type of vehicle (lorries, vans, new cars, old cars* Etc.), it will state what an appropriate seat belt is.

You you must wear the seat belt as listed there.

---

- The chassis on old cars often isn't strong enough to support the strength required by a seat belt, so it would either be pointless or worse. This means pre 1966 (in the UK at least)